# Python: Program keeps repeating if statement

Tags: python

Im trying to do a code that asks if you are a student or faculty and if you're a resident and applies certaain discount depending on the answer, but for some reason, it keeps repeating the food cost input. Also this is my first time , sorry if i make a mistake in my posting.

like this (S)tudent or (F)aculty? S
Dorm resident? (Y/N) Y
Food cost: $ 4
Food cost: $ 4
Food cost: $ 4
etc...

it should go

like this (S)tudent or (F)aculty? S
Dorm resident? (Y/N) Y
Food cost: $ 4
Non-food cost: $2
Total cost $: etc.

```
def calculate_food(user_type,gets_discount):
  cost = raw_input("Food cost: $")
  cost = float(cost)
  if calculate_food('S',True):
    return cost * .9
  elif calculate_food('S',False):
    return cost * .95
  elif calculate_food('F',True):
    return cost * .8
  else:
    return cost * .95
def calculate_other():
  cost = raw_input("Non-food cost: $")
  cost = float(cost)
  return cost * 1.055
def calculate_total():
  user_type = raw_input("(S)tudent or (F)aculty?")
  if user_type == 'S':
    gets_discount = raw_input("Dorm resident? (Y/N)")
    if gets_discount == 'Y':
      gets_discount == True
    elif gets_discount == 'N':
      gets_discount == False
    else:
      print("Invalid input, Y or N only.")
      quit()
  elif user_type == 'F':
    gets_discount = raw_input("Meal plan? (Y/N)")
    if gets_discount == 'Y':
      gets_discount == True
    elif gets_discount == 'N':
      gets_discount == False
    else:
      print("Invalid input, Y or N only.")
      quit()
  else:
    print("Invalid input, S or F only.")
    quit()
  calculate_food(user_type,gets_discount)
  calculate_other()
  totalCost = calculate_other() + calculate_food(user_type,gets_discount)
  print"Total cost: $",totalCost
calculate_total()
```

Comment: `==` is a comparison. You aren't assigning anything to True or False

Comment: @cricket_007 among other problems...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are calling `calculate_food` from within the `calculate_food` function itself. This is called [recursion](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Recursion_(computer_science)). And because your function **always** recursively calls itself, it will loop forever. (Deliberately implemented recursive functions would use some kind of test to determine when they no longer needed to call themselves again, and at that point the recursion would stop and unwind, so the original function call could complete.)

Here's your problem function:

```
def calculate_food(user_type,gets_discount):
  cost = raw_input("Food cost: $")
  cost = float(cost)
  if calculate_food('S',True):
    return cost * .9
  elif calculate_food('S',False):
    return cost * .95
  elif calculate_food('F',True):
    return cost * .8
  else:
    return cost * .95
```

So this can only get as far as `if calculate_food('S',True)`, because at that point `calculate_food` is being called again, and so another call of this function starts an executes `cost = raw_input("Food cost: $")`.

Perhaps you instead meant to check the values of the `user_type` and `gets_discount` parameters? You should understand that `if calculate_food('S',True)` does not mean "if the calculate_food function was called with the parameters 'S' and True...", rather it means "call the calculate_food function again with the parameters 'S' and True and then if the return value of that call is true..."

So your function should look something like this:

```
def calculate_food(user_type,gets_discount):
  cost = raw_input("Food cost: $")
  cost = float(cost)
  if user_type == 'S' and gets_discount:
    return cost * .9
  elif user_type == 'S' and not gets_discount:
    return cost * .95
  elif user_type == 'F' and gets_discount:
    return cost * .8
  else:
    return cost * .95
```

Answer (score 1):

Currently any time `calculate_food` is called, it will always ask for input and then call `calculate_food`, which in turn asks for input and calls `calculate_food`, etc. I think what you actually want for `calculate_food` is to check whether `user_type` and `gets_discount` satisfy certain conditions, and not to call `calculate_food` again.

```
def calculate_food(user_type,gets_discount):
    cost = raw_input("Food cost: $")
    cost = float(cost)
    if user_type == 'S' and gets_discount:
        return cost * .9
    elif user_type == 'S':
        return cost * .95
    elif user_type == 'F' and gets_discount:
        return cost * .8
    else:
        return cost * .95
```

Answer (score 1):

In order to learn why your code is self-repeating i'd suggest you get familiar with the concept of [recursion](https://www.python-course.eu/recursive_functions.php). Also, make sure you understand a little bit more about [functions](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/python/python_functions.htm), definitions, calls, return values...

In any case, here's a little review of your snippet showing you some alternatives patterns to handle common problems. It's introducing new concepts like dictionaries, exceptions and lambdas though:

```
def str2bool(v):
    if v.lower() in ("y"):
        return True
    elif v.lower() in ("n"):
        return False
    else:
        raise Exception("Invalid input, Y or N only")


def calculate_food(user_type, gets_discount):
    cost = float(raw_input("Food cost: $"))

    return {
        ("S", True): lambda x: x * .9,
        ("S", False): lambda x: x * .95,
        ("F", True): lambda x: x * .8,
        ("F", False): lambda x: x * .95,
    }[(user_type, gets_discount)](cost)


def calculate_other():
    return float(raw_input("Non-food cost: $")) * 1.055


def calculate_total():
    user_type = raw_input("(S)tudent or (F)aculty?")
    if user_type not in ("S", "F"):
        print("Invalid input, S or F only.")
        quit()

    try:
        gets_discount = str2bool(raw_input({
            "S": "Dorm resident? (Y/N)",
            "F": "Meal plan? (Y/N)"
        }[user_type]))
    except Exception as e:
        print("Invalid input, Y or N only.")
        quit()

    food_prize = calculate_food(user_type, gets_discount)
    other_prize = calculate_other()
    print("Total cost: $ {}".format(food_prize + other_prize))

calculate_total()
```

Also, make sure you test thoroughly your software... The above script contains some unhandled exceptions at purpose (Tip: Users can input all sort of things and your software should handle it gracefully)

Have fun ;D!